# Hausdorff with neighbourhood regular is regular.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ topological space Hausdorff.

show that:
If for any $x\in X$ exists a neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ such that $closure(V)$ is regular then $X$ is regular.
Is $X$ normal?
How could I begin to solve this problem?

Comment: The truth is not specified. I guess yes ....

Comment: write down and unpack the definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume K closed and x not in K.
Exists open U nhood x with regular $\bar U$.

Case K and $\bar U$ disjoint.
U and X - $\bar U$ are open sets that separate x and K.

Case K and $\bar U$ are not disjoint,
K $\cap$ $\bar U$ is closed within $\bar U$ and x not in K $\cap$ $\bar U$.
Now use the regularity of $\bar U$ to find open sets that separate x and K.